# A property of parallelism in a figure formed by an ellipse and a circle with same area

Tags: triangles, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Consider a circle of radius $r$ and an ellipse of semiaxes $a>b$, both centered at the origin $O$, with area of the circle and the ellipse being equal, such as in the Figure. The ellipse has an angle $\hat{ROP}$ between its major semiaxis and coordinate axis $x$. Distance $OP = r$. Also $OR=r$, and $R$ is both on the ellipse and the circle
Given a horizontal line $m$ that passes through point $P$, we know that the acute angle between that line and the semiaxis $a$ is equal to $\hat{ROP}$. I can see graphically that line $m$ intersects the ellipse at point $Q$, which coincides with the endpoint of semiaxis $b$. However I need to prove this algebraically: Prove that the distance between the intersection of $m$ with the ellipse and the origin,  is $b$.
Any suggestions are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Exactly, point $R$ is both on the circle and the ellipse

Comment: In other words, $OR=r$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By comparison of areas:

$$\pi r^2=\pi ab$$

Let us take the principal axes of the ellipse as coordinate axes: the coordinates $(x,y)$ of intersection point $R$ are solutions of the following system:

$$\begin{cases}x^2&+&y^2&=&ab& Circle\\\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}&+&\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}&=&1&Ellipse\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}x^2&+&y^2&=&ab\\b^2 x^2&+&a^2y^2&=&a^2b^2\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

whose solutions are:

$$x^2=\dfrac{a^2b}{a+b} \ \ \text{then, by symmetry between} \ x,y, \ \ y^2=\dfrac{b^2a}{a+b}$$

Let us consider, among the four solutions, the coordinates of $M$ situated in the fourth quadrant: $x>0,y<0$, in order to "stick" to the case represented on the graphics, i.e.,

$$x=\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2b}{a+b}}, \ \ \ \ \ \ y=-\sqrt{\dfrac{b^2a}{a+b}}\tag{2}$$

OR and OP will be parallel if and only if slope(OR) = slope(QP).

Using (2)

$$slope(OR)=\dfrac{y}{x}=-\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{a}},$$

$$slope(QP)=-\dfrac{OQ}{OP}=-\dfrac{b}{r}=-\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{ab}}$$

which are indeed identical.

Comment: I am struggling... I understand perfectly the system (1), but I can't get to simplify the solutions for $x$ and $y$ to put in the equation for $OR$, in order to use the slope to obtain $y$ in the equation for $QP$, which is what I think I must do, but please enlighten me...

Comment: Which solutions $x^2=..., y^2=...$ have you found ?

Comment: Look, I have written a simplified version of the system.

Comment: The solutions I have found are $x^2=ab-(a^2-ab)/[(a^2/b^2)-1]$; the second term of the RHS being $y^2$...

Comment: Surely I am missing some logic here

Comment: No, I just checked, it's exact, simplified, it is $x^2=\dfrac{a^2b}{a+b}$. (I have used relationship $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$). You wouldn't have struggled so much with the simplified system (the less fractions we have, the best it is...). For symmetry reasons $y^2=\dfrac{b^2a}{a+b}$.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I still don't understand how to use this to prove that $OQ=b$. The quotient $y/x$ would help but with these solutions I have to use square roots... I am lost

Comment: @PMacmutton Hint: $\tan POR=\tan OPQ=\sqrt{\frac ba} $.

Comment: @user is right. Besides, the slope of line segment $QP$ is $\dfrac{OQ}{OP}=\dfrac{b}{r}=\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{ab}}=...$ (one should maybe give these quantities a minus sign to cope with the case shown on the figure)

Comment: Thanks @user, but my original question is why $b$ is on the numerator there... i already saw that equation in a book, but I don't get the algebra that leads there

Comment: @PMacmuttonp because $y^2/x^2=b/a $. (see the solution in the answer).

Comment: Said otherwise, if a point $M$ has coordinates $(x_M,y_M)$ the slope of OM is $\dfrac{y_M}{x_M}$

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot, I get it now. Sorry for the "delay"

Comment: Thanks for your thanks. Fruitful exchanges, that I have incorporated now in a "full" answer.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to be more informative.